# React lazy loading data with Spring boot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, async-await, material-table

My solution is based on a front app React , redux and material-u and a backend Springboot app.

I have a Rest API that fetch a big number of records from the database. This creates a delay on the UI and I would like to prevent this.

**Table component:**

```
export default function Export(props) {
  return (
   <div>
  <MaterialTable
    title={<Typography variant="h6">{}</Typography>}
    data={props.data}
    options={{
      pageSize: 50,
      pageSizeOptions: [50, 100, 150],
      search: true,
      sorting: false,
      headerStyle: {
        fontWeight: "bold",
        padding: "4px",
      },
    }}
  ></MaterialTable>
</div>
 );
}


export const getExportByLastModifiedDate = (lastModifiedDate) => {
 return async (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({ type: EXPORT_BY_LASTMODIFEDDATE_START });
   await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/api/export?lastModifiedDate=" + lastModifiedDate,
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    dispatch({
      type: EXPORT_BY_LASTMODIFEDDATE_SUCCESS,
      payload: response.data,
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    dispatch({ type: EXPORT_BY_LASTMODIFEDDATE_ERROR, payload: error });
  });
 };
};
```

**Backend API:**

```
@GetMapping("/export")
public ResponseEntity<List<ExportDto>> getExportByLastModifiedDate(@RequestParam(value = "lastModifiedDate", required = true) String lastModifiedDate) {
    
    Optional<List<ExportDto>> optional = Optional.ofNullable(service.getExportByLastModifiedDate(lastModifiedDate));
    return optional.map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(response)).orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get the first 1000 records and to render them to the UI while in the backend the process will continue.

How can I do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution may be adding pagination support in your `query` and `backend rest api`. For example, first you call your backend with `page=0&pageSize=1000`, this will return you first 1000 records, after this records are loaded, you will then call the backend with `page=1&pageSize=1000`, this will return the next 1000 records.

Spring boot has good pagination support for pagination if you are using `spring data jpa`. If you are using `native query` then, most databases has syntax supporting this kind of pagination and you need to modify your query for pagination.